# Best way to get both modulo and result of division?

Tags: java, performance

Seeing as modulo and integer division are closely related, you'd think it would make sense to get both values in one operation. Are there languages that have this capability?

Follow up question: For languages that don't have this capability, is it best to compute the modulo by subtracting off the result of the division * denominator?

```java
// In java, if I want both values I need to do this:
int myNumber = 125;
int denominator = 6;

int division = myNumber / denominator;  // 20
int modulo1   = myNumber % denominator;  // 5

// Follow up: Is this a more efficient way to compute the modulo?
int modulo2 = myNumber - division * denominator;
```

Comment: Doing both operations is not going to affect your program’s performance.  Each line takes nanoseconds to execute at worst.  Consider how many math operations take place each second in a modern videogame.

Comment: Ignore my previous comment about negative numbers. When you find yourself asking "is this more efficient?", the quickest way to find out is to run both of them and time how long they take. Different hardware may produce different results

Comment: You need to consider that if you need to do this often it would make sense to write a method.  But invoking a method can also decrease performance.  But having run some simple tests I can assure you that any noticeable performance hit would not be due to this operation.   After about 10M iterations, the difference in combined running time between using operators and computing as you suggested was about `.1` seconds.  And this included putting results in an ArrayList so the compiler would not optimize out unused results.

Answer (score 6):

When you use `BigInteger`, you can query quotient and remainder in one operation

```java
BigInteger myNumber = BigInteger.valueOf(125), denominator = BigInteger.valueOf(6);
BigInteger[] result = myNumber.divideAndRemainder(denominator);
System.out.println(myNumber + " / " + denominator + " = " + result[0]);
System.out.println(myNumber + " % " + denominator + " = " + result[1]);
```

```
125 / 6 = 20
125 % 6 = 5
```

However, when you are calculating with integral values, it’s best to trust the JIT compiler/ hotspot optimizer.

E.g. when I use

```java
static void test(int myNumber, int denominator) {
    int division = myNumber / denominator;  // 20
    int modulo1   = myNumber % denominator;  // 5

    // prevent over-optimization
    if(division != 20 || modulo1 != 5) throw new AssertionError();
}
```

and run `test(125, 6)` often enough, I get the following compiled native code with JDK 11/x86

```
  0x0000029f3ef97b2c: mov     eax,edx
  0x0000029f3ef97b2e: test    r8d,r8d
  0x0000029f3ef97b31: je      29f3ef97b63h      ;*idiv {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                ; - SO71326541::test@2 (line 23)

  0x0000029f3ef97b33: cmp     eax,80000000h
  0x0000029f3ef97b38: jne     29f3ef97b42h
  0x0000029f3ef97b3a: xor     edx,edx
  0x0000029f3ef97b3c: cmp     r8d,0ffffffffh
  0x0000029f3ef97b40: je      29f3ef97b46h
  0x0000029f3ef97b42: cdq
  0x0000029f3ef97b43: idiv    eax,r8d
  0x0000029f3ef97b46: mov     r11d,edx
  0x0000029f3ef97b49: cmp     eax,14h
  0x0000029f3ef97b4c: jne     29f3ef97b72h      ;*if_icmpne {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                ; - SO71326541::test@11 (line 27)

  0x0000029f3ef97b4e: cmp     edx,5h
  0x0000029f3ef97b51: jne     29f3ef97b86h      ;*if_icmpeq {reexecute=0 rethrow=0 return_oop=0}
                                                ; - SO71326541::test@16 (line 27)
```

We can clearly see that the two operations, `myNumber / denominator` and `myNumber % denominator` have been fused into a single `idiv` instruction.